# What plant is this: yellow/orange berries

Tags: identification

What plant could this possibly be?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This looks like rose hips.  I found [this picture](http://petalena.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/rose_hips.jpg) of rose hips that are a similar color.  Most rose hips images I found show them as being red however.

Answer (score 2):

The total absence of leaves makes ID much more difficult, so if you have any leaves, put those on in a picture. If the plant was prickly, it could be Pyracantha, otherwise a Cotoneaster variety, or it could be Sea Buckthorn (less likely), or a rose, or even a tree. Some Sorbus varieties have orange berries. Given the absence of any foliage at all, it might well be rosehips, though these are rather small and, as Timothy Martin says, are usually red, but it's possible the ones you have there weren't fully ripe when collected.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a chinaberry plant, cousin of the Neem I believe.

Comment: can you add some more about you identified this plant?  What about the berries identifies it as Chinaberry? Do you mean Melia azedarach?